# ADO.NET EF Composite primary key - can not update foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

I have following entities:
[image]

In my code I need to update the `FKCategoryID` in entity `BudgetPost` but I'm getting the following error:

> FKCategoryID is part of the object's
>   key information

Is it any way to update the key in this case or it's not possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is it a part of the composite key?   As long as FKBudgetID is a part of the composite primary key you won't be able to modify it.  If you want to enforce uniqueness in the combination of FKCategoryID and FKBudgetID, use a UNIQUE constraint instead.